# I need to show my data status by its phase

Tags: laravel

I need to view my database by phase, I'm using laravel 8.
My current table in database are:

[image: my database table]

| id | user | phase | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | phase 1 | done |
| 2 | 1 | phase 2 | on_progress |
| 3 | 1 | phase 3 | not_started_yet |
| 4 | 2 | phase 1 | done |
| 5 | 2 | phase 2 | on_progress |
| 6 | 2 | phase 3 | not_started_yet |
| 7 | 3 | phase 1 | done |
| 8 | 3 | phase 2 | on_progress |
| 9 | 3 | phase 3 | not_started_yet |

I need to show my data like this

[image: view i wanted]

| user | phase 1 | phase 2 | phase 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | done | on progress | not started yet |
| 2 | done | on progress | not started yet |
| 3 | done | on progress | not started yet |

My controller

```
public function index()
{
    return view ('dashboard.index'), [
        'data' => Data::all()
    ];
}
```

I don't know how to make the view

Comment: use groupBy in `Data::groupBy('phase')->get()`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the question is how to transform the data to look like this or how to write a blade view to output them as you need.

I will show you how you can transform your data the way you described and then writing the blade view should be just a matter of looping and echoing with some styles.

If this data represents an eloquent model, you should have the following collection:

```php
collect([
    ['user' => 1, 'phase' => 'phase 1', 'status' => 'done'],
    ['user' => 1, 'phase' => 'phase 2', 'status' => 'on_progress'],
    ['user' => 1, 'phase' => 'phase 3', 'status' => 'not_started_yet'],
    ['user' => 2, 'phase' => 'phase 1', 'status' => 'done'],
    ['user' => 2, 'phase' => 'phase 2', 'status' => 'on_progress'],
    ['user' => 2, 'phase' => 'phase 3', 'status' => 'not_started_yet'],
    ['user' => 3, 'phase' => 'phase 1', 'status' => 'done'],
    ['user' => 3, 'phase' => 'phase 2', 'status' => 'on_progress'],
    ['user' => 3, 'phase' => 'phase 3', 'status' => 'not_started_yet'],
])
```

So you first need to `group by user` and then `pluck` the `phase` and the `status` together.

The following is doing what you want:

```php
collect([
    ['user' => 1, 'phase' => 'phase 1', 'status' => 'done'],
    ['user' => 1, 'phase' => 'phase 2', 'status' => 'on_progress'],
    ['user' => 1, 'phase' => 'phase 3', 'status' => 'not_started_yet'],
    ['user' => 2, 'phase' => 'phase 1', 'status' => 'done'],
    ['user' => 2, 'phase' => 'phase 2', 'status' => 'on_progress'],
    ['user' => 2, 'phase' => 'phase 3', 'status' => 'not_started_yet'],
    ['user' => 3, 'phase' => 'phase 1', 'status' => 'done'],
    ['user' => 3, 'phase' => 'phase 2', 'status' => 'on_progress'],
    ['user' => 3, 'phase' => 'phase 3', 'status' => 'not_started_yet'],
])
    ->groupBy('user')
    ->map(function ($user, $userId) {
        return $user->pluck('phase', 'status')
            ->prepend($userId, 'user')
            ->toArray();
    })
    ->toArray();
```

which returns the following array:

```php
[
    1 => [
       'user' => 1,
       'done' => 'phase 1',
       'on_progress' => 'phase 2',
       'not_started_yet' => 'phase 3',
    ],
    2 => [
       'user' => 2,
       'done' => 'phase 1',
       'on_progress' => 'phase 2',
       'not_started_yet' => 'phase 3',
    ],
    3 => [
       'user' => 3,
       'done' => 'phase 1',
       'on_progress' => 'phase 2',
       'not_started_yet' => 'phase 3',
    ],
]
```